# Horrible input sound on any distro

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, voip, microphone, alsamixer

I've been toying around with several distros in my endless effort to ditch windows and stick to linux but I haven't been able to work this out. I used to have a desktop where everything just worked but now I have a laptop (acer aspire e 15 e5-575g-52rj) and I'm having a very annoying issue when it comes to VoIP chatting which I regularly use. I'm experiencing this issues with Skype and Discord, everyone who's listening on the same channel or chat says that my mic sounds like it has some sort of crazy amplification but I've checked pavucontrol and alsamixer without finding anything useful. The only thing I saw was that discord uses something called WebRTC and Skype uses Chrome Sound. Dunno if that's relevant or anything.

I wanted to know if my mic was the issue so I unplugged it from my computer and tried to use the internal one on linux, it didn't work so I'm thinking it's a driver issue, but I don't really know what to do now. I tried Ubuntu, Fedora, Solus and now I'm on Manjaro and I'm having the exact same issue on every single one of them.

Also, I tried listening to my own mic on linux using this command:
`pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1` and it worked just fine, I mean I didn't hear any of the issues people talked about. I thought it could be discord's or skype's postprocessing software (don't know if that's its name but I didn't know what else to call it) but I would'nt really know how to troubleshoot that. 
`

Comment: 1) Are you indicating that you did not only switch from desktop to notebook but also use a new microphone since then, or did your microphone work with the desktop and Linux? 2) All VoIP providers offer pseudo answering machines which call you back and replay what they recorded. Did you use any of these so far?

Comment: In addition to `module-loopback`, you can `arecord` or `parecord` your mic to check for distortions. If that sounds right, too, then I'd assume it's some kind of bug in discord or Skype (wrong sample rate? bad conversion?) And you won't be able to debug it in Skype, because it's closed source.

Comment: I switched from Desktop to a notebook but I didn't have this issues back then. I still use the same mic though. I actually tried those two methods after posting and it sounded alright. So I'm guessing that the problem is within the VoIP software. Although I turned on my machine today and now I have no sound output either lol, so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Had very distorted sound in Skype calls, found fix by launching Skype from terminal like this:

```
PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=90 skypeforlinux
```

Works like a charm every time.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984795/distorted-headphone-sound-when-using-skype-for-linux/984885)

Sound in Discord breaks up a lot; haven't found fix yet